# Android studio 2.1.1 gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed android studio 2.1.1. And when I'm opening a old project I'm getting this error-

> Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components are ready to
>   update: Android Support Repository, Google Repository, Google APIs
>   Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android SDK Tools 25.1.7 8:18:58 AM
>   Gradle sync started 8:19:39 AM Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
>              Searched in the following locations:
>              file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
>              file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
>              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
>              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar

Please help. I'm beginner here...

Comment: share graddle code

Comment: create a new project and copy the gradle version from this new project's build.gradle to old project build.gradle..

Comment: there are a lot of Gradle version available ,which Gradle version your android studio is using can be known by creating new project n checking its build.gradle... I use this method to remove my Gradle issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Download the files from the links provided i.e

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom

And

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar

Then paste this files in their appropriate places i.e

C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/

Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum gradle version supported by Android Studio 2.1.1 (which here refers to android plugin 2.1.0) is 2.10.

In your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your project update the gradle version to 2.10, by editing the `distributionUrl` filed

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

The lastest version as of now is `2.13` , you can also update to that.

NOTE : This will update gradle used by your project, to change the gradle used by Android Studio , change the gradle version in settings.

Reference : [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)